# AsyncTask clears response in onPostExecute

Tags: android-asynctask

I am sending request using soap method. Then I am storing Response in String variable in doInBackground and then checking condition onPostExecute.
But as I have checked it step by step, I came to know that It is clearing value onPostExecute.
How to solve this prob ?

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        username = new PropertyInfo();
        username.setName("UserName");
        username.setValue(Username);
        username.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(username);

        password = new PropertyInfo();
        password.setName("Password");
        password.setValue(Password);
        password.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(password);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envp.dotNet = true;
        envp.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envp.getResponse();
            Response = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }

        if (Response.equals("Fail")) {
            etPassword.setText("");
            textValidation.setText("UserName Or Password is Wrong.");

        } else {
            etUsername.setText("");
            etPassword.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some code of your problem would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

How do you declare your AsyncTask class ?

According to the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
>   Progress, the type of the progress units published during the
>   background computation. Result, the type of the result of the
>   background computation. Not all types are always used by an
>   asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void.

It should be something like :

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Result>
```

This will define `doInBackground()` signature as follow :

```
protected Result doInBackground(Param... params)
```

You can then return the result at the end of `doInBackground()` instead of `null`.

**Edit :**

Applied to you example, it should look to something like this :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, int[], String> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        username = new PropertyInfo();
        username.setName("UserName");
        username.setValue(Username);
        username.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(username);

        password = new PropertyInfo();
        password.setName("Password");
        password.setValue(Password);
        password.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(password);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envp.dotNet = true;
        envp.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envp.getResponse();
            // return your result here
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return null if something went wrong
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }

        if (result == null) {
            // handle null here, for example :
            // result = "Fail";
        }

        // use "Fail".equals(result) instead of result.equals("Fail")
        // to avoid error if result is null
        if ("Fail".equals(result)) { 
            etPassword.setText("");
            textValidation.setText("UserName Or Password is Wrong.");

        } else {
        etUsername.setText("");
        etPassword.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```